# Is the inequality $a-b \leq a^2 - b^2$ true for all $a>b$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$?

Tags: inequality

I was just wondering if there was a formal way to prove the following:

$$a-b \leq a^2 - b^2 \quad \forall a>b \text{ and } a,b \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$$

Intuitively it makes perfect sense, but is there a simple way to prove it?

Comment: Hint:  can you prove that $a+b>1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I hope my english is good enough, but let us try to find a solution together.

1. Lets look at our formula. We should be able to observe the following:

   $a -b \leq a^2-b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$
2. Since we know a > b, we conclude that our term $(a-b)$ is a positive number. So we are able to derive an equivalent inequality by dividing by $(a-b)$. Lets summarize:

   $a -b \leq (a-b)(a+b)$ is equivalent to

   $1 \leq (a+b)$ (since we divide both, right and left, by (a-b))
3. Last we observe the inequality:

   $1 \leq (a+b)$

   This holds true since a is atleast 1. Which we derive from the fact, that b < a and both are from $\mathbb{N}_0$

Comment: In fact the strict inequality $1<a+b$ holds, because $\Bbb N_{>0}$ doesn't contain $0$. So we get $a-b<a^2-b^2$.

Comment: You're perfectly right. I didn't see that and thought a and b are from $\mathbb{N}_0$. But since the questions is asked for $\leq$ the proof should still work just fine.

Comment: Yes, the prooof is fine.